# What command can I use to locate tnt in a players inventory?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to make something in Minecraft with security doors but I can’t find out how to locate a specific item in a players inventory shulker box, ender chest, or hand. I need assistance to find the correct command for pocket edition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if a certain item is in a player inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/371922/how-to-tell-if-a-certain-item-is-in-a-player-inventory)

Answer (score 2):

You are unable to locate an item in a shulker box or enderchest - this will require game file editing.

Using commands, you are able to clear their inventory of tnt, or link any other command.

First, custom command if tnt is found:

```
execute at @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:tnt"}]}] run <Your command here>
```

If you would like for no player to have tnt in their inventory, run

```
clear @a tnt
```

every tick (using a repeating command block)

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma Hi Marco - /toggleitem is not a vanilla minecraft command. If I am mistaken, please link a reputable source. Thanks

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma Hi again Marco - /recipe is only for the Java edition of the game. -Detailed here: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#recipe

Comment: Your entirely right, my source seems to provide wrong information. Ill remove my comments to prevent discussion. Your answer covers it then

Comment: Remark: The `/clear` command does not remove items from shulker boxes or the ender chest, at least that's how it works in Java Minecraft.

Comment: Thanks! @FabianRöling - I am working on making my posts clear - Next time perhaps you could edit to show me what to do next time? Thanks

Comment: Sure, but not in this case. Your answer is pretty much as good as it gets, since what the asker wants is impossible in MCPE.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command:

```
clear @p tnt
```

When this returns true, have it do whatever you want. Note that that will take away the TNT, although you could hook it up to a system that gives it back once it is taken.

*Note that the other answer provided above is for Java edition, and the command won't work. This command will work.*